# Why .d.ts file module declaration doesn't work in angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created file called global.d.ts in src folder with following content:

```
declare module 'ol-contextmenu';
```

I have also tried to locate it in root, in node-modules/@types but it just doesn't work.

My component imports ol-contextmenu (that doesn't have types) like this:

```
import ContextMenu from 'ol-contextmenu';
```

I have tried to edit tsconfig.json in multiple ways for the .d.ts file to be found. For example:

```
"include": [
  "src/global.d.ts"
]
```

But I always get error:

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'ol-contextmenu'.
> 'C:/dev/nis/NIS/ClientApp/node_modules/ol-contextmenu/dist/ol-contextmenu.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install @types/ol-contextmenu` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
> file containing `declare module 'ol-contextmenu';`
>
> 5 import ContextMenu from 'ol-contextmenu';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have also tried to copy the file to node-modules/@types but the error is always same.

Answer (score 2):

You can take one of the ways declared [here in the Typescript's official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html#editing-the-packagejson) in order to make your Typescript aware that you will be using ECMAScript modules format instead of CommonJs modules format.

In my case I went across the way of creating the **index.d.ts** file **under the src folder** of my Angular app, and inside of it, declare all the js files that you need to declare as an ECMAScript module, for example in your case:

```js
declare module 'ol-contextmenu';
```

Why? Well, as per the doc:

> TypeScript replicates the node resolution for modules in a
> package.json, with an additional step for finding .d.ts files.
> Roughly, the resolution will first check the optional "types" field,
> then the "main" field, and finally will try index.d.ts in the root.